# What aria role to use for a forum signature?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

To improve accessibility, what role should I use for completely unrelated content such as a forum signature? Since it's completely unrelated to the main content and would frequently repeat, I thought it might even be a good idea to use aria-hidden="true" on it to make the experience of reading a forum thread with a screen reader more fluid, although according to MDN, aria-hidden "should not be used on a focusable element".

Comment: Do you have an example of what types of content are allowed in the signature? For example do they allow images, hyperlinks, block quotes etc. Also what is the structure of the forum in the first place, do you use the `<article>` element for each post for example?

Comment: @Graham Ritchie Yes, I use <article> for each post, as I've read this is the correct thing to do. The signature can contain links, images (and therefore also image-links), block quotes, as well as some basic text formatting like bold, italics and underline. It's structured like a classic phpbb/vbulletin old school forum, and I'm currently looking to make the html template more accessible.

Comment: Last question, is this a forum where you would be having a lot of too and fro conversations, i.e. could my signature appear 20 times on a page as we have a discussion on a topic?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie It depends on the thread, probably not 20 times but it would not be completely unusual for it to appear 5-8 times a page, if there's not a lot of people participating in the conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments there are two things I would implement:

### Item 1 - a `<footer>`

Put the signature in a `<footer>` element, it is the most appropriate element for if you are using `<article>` for each post.

I would also suggest you put an `aria-label` on each footer that says something like `aria-label="signature for {username}"` just to make it clear to people who use a screen reader.

### Item 2 - keyboard navigation

People who use a screen reader will be fine if you have structured the page correctly and able to skip between posts without having to always listen to a signature.

However for keyboard users who rely on the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key I would recommend adding keyboard shortcuts to jump between posts so they don't have to keep tabbing past signatures.

An easy way to do this would be to implement keyboard shortcut keys for jumping between posts. "J" and "K" are widely used keys for previous and next items.

However I would also suggest a way to switch this feature off, just in case it interferes with a screen reader (as "k" is "next link" in most screen readers).